# Can I submit form data from one controller to ruby on rails api controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm relatively new to this, so bear with me if I don't follow all the rules or post in a proper way.  Long story short, I have a rails app receiving data through an api controller.  I can post with postman, and everything works fine.  However, I have found the need to manually enter some measurements, and add data to the columns of existing measurements.

Can I submit form data to the same table as the api controller?  I could create a separate manual entries controller, but it seems more complicated to view measurements from two controllers, as my goal is to display the most recent measurement.   Thanks.

Edit--  I will try to explain better.  I have added my database schema.  I have multiple sensors inputting data into the api to track levels in bins.  However, not all bins will have sensors, and there is a possibility that a sensor will fail and I will need to input measurements.  I can do it with postman, but would like to be able to set up a form that will allow me to input the parameters into the measurements table similar to how I do with my 'bins' controller.  Also, I have only been working with Rails and web based programming for 2 months.  I have very little experience, but have learned a great deal.  Thanks.

```html
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2019_03_06_131737) do

  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "bins", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.decimal "diameter"
    t.decimal "total_height"
    t.decimal "inside_height_diff"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.decimal "response_angle"
    t.decimal "hopper_height"
    t.integer "inside_offset"
    t.integer "outside_offset"
    t.decimal "ring_height"
  end

  create_table "measurements", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "outside"
    t.integer "inside"
    t.bigint "bin_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "comment"
    t.boolean "outside_fill"
    t.boolean "inside_fill"
    t.index ["bin_id"], name: "index_measurements_on_bin_id"
  end

  create_table "shipments", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "ticket"
    t.date "ship_date"
    t.time "ship_time"
    t.string "commodity"
    t.string "owner"
    t.string "carrier"
    t.decimal "gross"
    t.decimal "tare"
    t.decimal "moisure"
    t.decimal "dock"
    t.decimal "test_weight"
    t.decimal "vom"
    t.string "comment"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  add_foreign_key "measurements", "bins"
end
```

```ruby
class Api::MeasurementsController < ApplicationController
  skip_forgery_protection

  def index
    measurements = Measurement.all
    render json: measurements
  end

  def create
    measurement = Measurement.create(
      outside: params[:outside],
      inside: params[:inside],
      bin_id: params[:bin_id],
      outside_fill: params[:outside_fill],
      inside_fill: params[:inside_fill],
      comment: params[:comment]
    )
    render json: measurement
  end

  def delete
    measurement = Measurement.find(params[:id])
    measurement.destroy
  end

  def update
    measurement = Measurement.find(params[:id])
    measurement.outside = params[:outside]
    measurement.inside = params[:inside]
    measurement.bin_id = params[:bin_id]
    measurement.outside_fill = params [:outside_fill]
    measurement.inside_fill = params [:inside_fill]
    measurement.comment = params [:comment]
    measurement.save!
    render json: measurement
  end

end
```

Comment: what do you mean by "manually enter some measurements" ?. How are you supposed to add those records ?, why not through postman ?. You could also create a Rake task and add them there using just `ActiveRecord`. It all depends on the requirements you have.

Comment: You can do it through rails console. Btw, read about [strong parameters](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters) - this them you can create/update in one line `measurement.update(update_params)`

Comment: The questions raised by @fanta are all important; without them we would not know what you want to achieve. I'd add one more question: what do you mean "add the data"? For an existing row (in a DB table), you can only either update some (or all) column values of the row or delete the entire row. Maybe the op can edit and update your question so future visitors do not have to go through the comments like this to understand the question?

Comment: @Vasilisa, I tried to run the update prams command, but got NameError (undefined local variable or method `measurements' for main:Object)

Comment: @superfarmer [This](https://gist.github.com/antarr/a456cb613b63586155f2abe74dfe771c) is what it should look like when using strong_parameters.

Comment: @AntarrByrd, great!

Comment: @superfarmer, you can use the same controller, just add html response format. You only need to think about authentication

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions, but no matter which way I try to do it, I get errors.  I haven’t had much time to work on this aspect of the app, so I made a separate controller to get it working.  When I get back to it, I will be sure to let you know what is blocking me from doing this.